# How to set global variables in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I have a markdown file with 4 chunks of code, but all chunks depend on the same initial database. When I run each chunk separately no problem happens, but when I knit, the problem begins: the chunks don't identify the variables and dataset already in the environment.
I solve this problem by loading all the datasets again, but it's not efficient.
How I turn all the variables in the first chunk into global variables, i.e., available to all chunks.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='hide', warning=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(tidyr)

variable1
variable2
````

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='hide', warning=FALSE}

variable1 %>%
ggplot2(aes(x = date, y = whatever) +
geom_line()
````

**For example, I have variables in the first chunk that will be plotted in another chunk. But these variables for some reason are not available.
Another problem: I have to load the packages in each chunk.**

I appreciate it if someone can help!

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example? That doesn't sound right - normally all chunks are executed in sequence and later chunks have access to objects created in earlier chunks.

Comment: I updated the post, maybe it’s easier to understand

Comment: Unfortunately your update doesn’t help: what you’re describing is *not* how R Markdown behaves. Instead, it behaves exactly like you expect it to.

Comment: When we ask for a "reproducible example" we're hoping for something that we can copy/paste into an Rmarkdown document, knit, and see the problem. Your example isn't valid - it will error out because `variable1` and `variable2` aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: Which is to say - the behavior you want is standard. The behavior you are getting is really weird. The best way to figure out why you're getting the weird behavior is to find a minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem. If you can find a short example that we can run that shows the problem, we can fix it on our end and tell you how to fix. If, on the other hand, the minimal example works fine for us but causes the problem for you, we know to begin looking at differences between our systems.

Answer (score 3):

You generally just use an initial block commonly labeled `setup`. And it does not even have to be a 'global' (in the sense of `<<-` assignment) variable: subsequent chunks are aware of earlier chunks.

#### Code

````
---
title: demo
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
suppressMessages(library(zoo))

startDate <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
```

Some text.


```{r code}
data <- zoo(1:3, order.by=startDate + 0:2)
print(data)
```
````

#### Output

With apologies for a screenshot

[image]